# Can't post a job on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm trying to post a job ad on Stack Overflow Careers, but I get a screen telling me:

> Great! Your account manager will reach out to you shortly
>   to help you complete and publish your Job Listing to Stack Overflow.

But nobody contacted me for over 10 days.

Answer (score 3):

I have reached out to our sales team to have someone contact you about this.

Comment: Can you please update your profile and mention you work for Stack Overflow? Better than having to include this as "signature", which is frowned upon in Stack Overflow. (bit ironic)

Comment: Updated and edited answer